# Gulp-Jekyll плагин jekyll-paginate, как установить?

Tags: gulp, jekyll

Как установить на gulp-jekyll плагин на paginate для разбивки блога на страницы?

Такая ошибка возникает:

```
[15:31:47] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
Configuration file: C:/Jekyll/vostoksisters/_config.yml
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-paginate or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  jekyll-paginate
[15:31:49] 'jekyll-build' errored after 2.63 s
[15:31:49] Error: 1
    at formatError (C:\Users\Vostok Sisters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vostok Sisters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at ChildProcess.cb (C:\Jekyll\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Спустя две минуты подсмотрел решение на ютубе, хотя там парень не использовал gulp.
Я сделал всего две вещи:

- Ввел команду в консоли (нужен предустановленный руби):
  `gem install jekyll-paginate`
- Указал введенной строкой в корневом `_config.yml`, что подключил гем:
  `gems: [jekyll-paginate]`

Comment: `gem` не является "командой в node.js".. Вы притянули в проект руби, оно того стоило?

Comment: @vp_arth, а-а... Значит, руби нужен. Он у меня тоже установлен.

Comment: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate - тут написано, что плагин больше не поддерживается

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/ - а тут - написано, что у Джекила из коробки уже есть пагинация.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, он не поддерживается, но работает. Вопрос не в том, что поддерживается, а что нет.

Comment: А, этот ваш джекил это и есть руби-тул.. Извиняюсь)

Comment: @YozhEzhi, ага, в версии 2x. Я второй не пользуюсь (как и все, кто работают с джекиллом).

Comment: @YozhEzhi, если что-то не поддерживается, то это совершенно не повод от этого отказываться. Много людей до сих пор сидят на jade, а не на pug, хотя разница там всего в паре инструкций.  Ничего страшного.

Comment: @VostokSisters не `в версии`, а `с версии` :)
"Вопрос не в том, что поддерживается, а что нет" - хозяин - барин, да.

Comment: @VostokSisters "если что-то не поддерживается, то это совершенно не повод от этого отказываться" - конечно. Можно ведь и форк сделать и самому баги править :)